# applying fubini's theorem

Tags: analysis

Let $I = [0 , 1]$; let $Q = I \times I$. Define $f: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ by letting $f(x , y) = 1 /q$
if y is rational and $X = p/q$, where p and q are positive integers with no
common factor; let $f(x, y) = 0$ otherwise.

need help with c)
[image]

Comment: have you done the first 2 parts?

Comment: yes just need c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, by part 2,

$\int_{y\in [0,1]} f(x,y) \text{d}y = 0$,

you should also find that:

$\int_{x\in [0,1]} f(x,y) \text{d}x = 0$

Note that this means $\int_{x\in[0,1]}\int_{y\in [0,1]} f(x,y) \text{d}y \text{d}x = \int 0 \text{d}x = 0 = \int 0 \text{d}y = \int_{y\in [0,1]} \int_{x\in [0,1]} f(x,y) \text{d}x\text{d}y$

which verifies Fubini's theorem which says you are allowed to exchange the order of integration in this case.

Comment: equal you mean?

Comment: @user115722 almost everywhere equals. should have said 'words'

Comment: @user115722 This was not clear in your other question, are you just doing Riemann integration or have you done Lebesgue integration? Even if you don't use Lebesgue integral, note you have shown by part (b) that the first two integrals are 0.

Comment: i'm confused sorry

Comment: @user115722 then please state in your question  1. have you done lebesgue integration? 2. what is the version of fubini's theorem you have been taught? this is a trivial question if the answer is yes to the first question.

Comment: Riemann integration.this question from munkres analysis book

Comment: @user115722 then why didn't you say so in the question? notice your other integration, someone actually commented 'what is your definition of integration?'

Comment: yes i was said riemann.hi say nothing and i deleted.thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user115722 no worries, have you solved the other problem?

Comment: yes i solved that.for this problem i said integral exist and equal zero then b) obvious.am i right?

Comment: @user115722 you mean from b), yes, assuming you got 0 for part b).

Comment: no i mean from a) :S

Comment: @user115722 yes you know it exists by (a).

Comment: ok thanks again :)